# Can't resize iTunes 11.0.2

Tags: itunes, display

I own a 2009 13-inch MacBook Pro and a 24-inch Led Cinema Display. I have always been able to resize iTunes horizontally and vertically (both being connected to the Display and not being connected).

However, for no apparent reason, I am not able to do that anymore in both situations. I can't make the window smaller than a certain width and height (being the minimum width approximately the width resolution of the 13-inch MacBook Pro).

[image]

I've tried resizing by using <kbd>option</kbd> and clicking on the green button, and using <kbd>option</kbd> and resizing, as recommended by other users but none of these solutions have worked.

**How can I allow resizing again?**

Comment: Due to my reputation, I can't post a [screenshot of my 13-inch MacBook Pro showing the minimum width and height allowed](http://imageshack.us/f/560/capturadepantalla201303.png/)  that would illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the the window's minimum width value. To do so just:

1. Go to `/Applications/iTunes.app/Conte­nts/Resources/YourLanguage.lpr­oj` and open the **AppConfig.plist** file. ( I'd use a text editor to open it, as it's easier to modify the file this way.)
2. Look for `<key>browser-window-minimum-width</key>` and change its integer value.
3. Save the file and Restart iTunes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Are there any established default values?

Comment: If there is, I must say that I don't know which is it.